# When deleting a file or a folder, it removes the wrong indexed file or folder from the GUI

Tags: 23.04

OS
Ubuntu 23.04
GENOME VERSION 44.0

[image]

As you can see from the above gif is that when I try to remove a file or a folder from terminal or using the GUI, the wrong indexed file or folder is disapeared but not removed.

bcz when I go to another directory and go back to test directory I find the file or folder was actually deleted.

Does anyone know what causing this behaviour and how to fix it?

Comment: Nautilus has many bugs. And probably this is one of them. Did you try to refresh the window by pressing F5?

Comment: @FedKad Yes it does the same as changing directory.

Is there any fix for this bug or what causing it ?

Comment: Does the `libgtk-4-1` update (released yesterday) fix your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, look for bug reports at: https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/nautilus/-/issues

If you are absolutely sure that your problem is not reported there, you can create a new bug report.

There seems to be a report similar to your problem at: https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/nautilus/-/issues/2990

In the meantime, you can use [Thunar File Manager](https://packages.ubuntu.com/lunar/thunar). It has much less visual bugs and it is more configurable.

---

After today's `libgtk-4-1` update this problems seems to have been solved. Can you test @MustafaAgha ?

Comment: It seems like gtk4-10-4 not available on Lunar Ubuntu 23.04, but available on the new upcoming Ubuntu 23.10. I don't if they are willing to support gtk 4-10-4 on Lunar or not.

Comment: simply solving this issue by enabling pre-released packages, a temp fix untill they add it to released packages. Then ```sudo apt install libgtk-4-1``` Then disable pre-released again